# rotate google maps with respect to the direction of movement of device (android)

Tags: android, google-maps

i am working on app which use google maps to plot the route in which the user is moving and its showing live. so i want to rotate the map according to the direction of movement of user.

if he/she moves right then the map rotate in such a way that the route he is moving always shows in foreword direction. like google maps navigation.

i think i should take the bearing between two location and then calculate some bearing and apply it to the maps.

any suggestion will be appreciated .

thank you

**update**

let me clarify my question as it is not that much understandable (thats what i think).

i want the my location pointer to point forward or upward always and the map to rotate itself when i move in an direction.

i think this makes my question more clear.

Comment: isnt't google maps working with the gyroscopes`?

Comment: Any updates on this one? I'm also facing the same issue.

Comment: i have solved this problem . soon i will post the answer .

Answer (score 2):

Calculate bearing between two points and then use it to set the camera position and then animate camera.

```
CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                                    .target(targetLatLng)
                                    .bearing(targetBearing)
                                    .zoom(mMap.getCameraPosition().zoom)
                                    .build();

mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition),
                            2000,
                            mCancelableCallback);
```

Comment: so the solution is working and yet to be tested. but can you make me understand that how this works. i get the bearing and set it to the camera and animate. and how will this suppose to make the camera move to the direction of movement of the device .

Comment: this is what i did to get the bearing.
double dLon = (dest.longitude - src.longitude);
            double y = Math.sin(dLon) * Math.cos(dest.latitude);
            double x = Math.cos(src.latitude) * Math.sin(dest.latitude) - Math.sin(src.latitude) * Math.cos(dest.latitude) * Math.cos(dLon);
            double brng = Math.toDegrees((Math.atan2(y, x)));
            brng = (360 - ((brng + 360) % 360));

Answer (score 0):

```
import android.location.Location;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
```

....

```
protected void animateToLocation(Location position)
    {
        if (mGoogleMap == null || position == null)
            return;

        float zoomLevel = mGoogleMap.getCameraPosition().zoom != mGoogleMap.getMinZoomLevel() ? mGoogleMap.getCameraPosition().zoom : 18.0F;
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(position.getLatitude(), position.getLongitude());
        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
            .target(latLng)
            .bearing(position.getBearing())
            .zoom(zoomLevel)
            .build();

        mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition), null);
    }
```

while `position:Location` can be fetched from **FusedApi#onLocationResult** or **LocationManager#OnLocationChanged**